# Как сделать чтобы код искал совпадения слов и с запятыми, и с заглавной буквы

Tags: java

есть код, который ищет совпадения слов в тексте.

```
     String[] message =  textArea.getText().split(" ");
     String usages = field.getText();
     for (int i = 0; i<message.length;i++) {
        if (message[i].equals(usages)){
            System.out.println(message[i]);
             }
        }
```

Но, если в field ввести слово с строчной буквы, а в textArea тоже самое слово будет с заглавной буквы, то программа не увидит совпадение, как это исправить ?

Comment: можно использовать библиотеку apache.commons, там есть StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase()

Comment: возпользуйтесь вместо метода `equals` методом `equalsIgnoreCase` он есть в классе `String`, тч никаких доп библиотек использовать не нужно

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov Век живи - век учись!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.equals` - проверка строк учитывая регистр.

`String.equalsIgnoreCase` - проверка строк **не** учитывая регистр.

Comment: Спасибо! А как мне игнорировать присутствие запятых или точек?

Comment: Перед вызовом `equalsIgnoreCase` удаляйте их у обоих строк. `oneString.replaceAll("[.,]", "")`

Comment: Спасибо большое !!))

Answer (score 2):

```
if (message[i].equalsIgnoreCase(usages)){
    System.out.println(message[i]);
}
```

О_о

Answer (score 1):

Привести слова к одному виду. Например, заменить все заглавные буквы строчными функцией `toLowerCase()`:

```
if (message[i].toLowerCase().equals(usages.toLowerCase()))
```

Comment: Не, так делать не надо. Посмотрите вариант Андрея Галкина. Во-первых, вы на каждой итерации цикла приводите i'тое к нижнему регистру, во вторых считаете заново usages (а оно не меняется). В общем куча лишних операций, которые безболезненно опускаются: не стоит лететь из Москвы в Питер через Владивосток, оверхэд дикий.